# Old laptop shutdowns during iso installation

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

The name of the laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A215-S4747

It has a AMD Turion 64 X2 Dual-Core Mobile Technology Chip.

It had 1 GB of RAM but i upgraded it to 4 GBs (It didn't boot when having 1gb so the RAM isn't the problem)

It used to have a 32bit Windows Vista (according to the manual). But according to wikipedia is a 64bit CPU.

The laptop no longer has the battery.

I use Ventoy to install/try the iso files.

I have tried to install latest version of debian-12-amd64 and debian-12-i386 but with both isos (32bit & 64bit) the laptop shutdowns when installing the base system.

I have also booted successfully into gparted-live-i686 and kali-linux-live-i386

What can be causing this problem?

The CPU tends to overheat but i use an external fan to keep the temperature low. Do you think the installation process overheats the CPU?

I think that maybe the hard drive is the one causing the problem, but it just an speculation

What to do guys think, does it have a solution? Should i try with archlinux if so, which version 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The CPU tends to overheat but i use an external fan to keep the temperature low. Do you think the installation process overheats the CPU?

This is by far the most obvious explanation.

Cooling an overheating laptop with an external fan is about as effective as cooling your pizza with a fan - by pointing the fan at the closed oven that it is still in.

Comment: MY TOSHIBA product: Satellite A105 with 1.5GB of RAM works with an external SSD with only BIOS boot stanza on internal HDD. I used Kubuntu 22.04 actually installed to SSD with UEFI, but BIOS boot skips UEFI.

Comment: That does in no way change anything about the answer stating the obvious: you have a device that you know has a heat problem. Now you're exercising it, and it crashes. And you all whether the heat problem might be to blame: yes.

Comment: So Is there a way i can reduce the overheating?